# Cloudinary how generate signature in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cloudinary

this is my code about cloudinary upload through widget, unfortunately i get upload error...i'm working on localhost, and the page where is placed this code is add.php page

```
<script src="//widget.cloudinary.com/global/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var generateSignature = function(callback, params_to_sign){
    $.ajax({
      url     : "http://localhost/add.php?public_id=sample_image&timestamp=1315060510",
      type    : "GET",
      dataType: "text",
      data    : { data: params_to_sign},
      complete: function() {console.log("complete")},
      success : function(signature, textStatus, xhr) { callback(signature); },
      error   : function(xhr, status, error) { console.log(xhr, status, error); }
    });
  }
</script>


    <script type="text/javascript">  
      $('#upload_widget_opener').cloudinary_upload_widget(
        { cloud_name: 'dammiunparere', api_key: '189XXXX42445355',
          upload_signature: generateSignature},

        function(error, result) { console.log(error, result) });
    </script>
```

Comment: Is this an "invalid signature" error that you're seeing? I see that you're passing some query string parameters in the `url` in addition to the `params_to_sign`. Note that Cloudinary expect you to sign **only** what's inside `params_to_sign`.

Answer (score 1):

Recently tried to sort out with this question. Here is simple solution:

It needs to have script on your server to generate signature, in this case it is file named "add.php". It should contain something like:

```
<?php
    define('CINCDIR', './inc/cloudinary/'); // path to cloudinary lib folder

    require_once(CINCDIR . 'Cloudinary.php');
    require_once(CINCDIR . 'Api.php');

    if(isset($_GET['data']))
    {
        echo \Cloudinary::api_sign_request($_GET['data'], '[PUT CLOUDINARY API SECRET HERE]');
    }
?>
```

Replace ***[PUT CLOUDINARY API SECRET HERE]***  with your cloudinary api secret.

This script needs cloudinary's PHP integration library. You should be able to download it from the following link: 
https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_php/tarball/master.
Copy all files from the src folder into your PHP project and include Cloudinary's PHP classes in your code:

```
require_once(CINCDIR . 'Cloudinary.php');
require_once(CINCDIR . 'Api.php');
```

Also, about JavaScript from your example above, you don't need to pass predefined parameters here:

```
url     : "http://localhost/add.php?public_id=sample_image&timestamp=1315060510"
```

Just URL of your script, in this case it is "http://localhost/add.php":

```
url     : "http://localhost/add.php"
```

Parameters added automatically, when generateSignature function is called.